# Angular http.get not sending Params

Tags: angular, parameters

My get

```
 getTaggedProofImage(proofGuid: string, pageGuid: string): 
    Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('pageGuid', pageGuid);
    const url = this.getProofTaggedImageUrl(proofGuid, pageGuid);
    return this.http.get(url, { params, observe: 'response'});
```

}

My response does not include the params for some reason. Currently, I am having to slice the pageGuid out of the URL.

```
 .subscribe((response) => {
    const pageGuid = response.url.slice(-51, -15);
```

I also tried attaching the data to the headers without any luck.[image]

I just want to get the pageGuid without having to slice the URL from the response. Should I be doing something else like using UrlSegment to get the correct piece of the URL I need?

Comment: Is your problem that params are not sent to the server, or just that you cannot see them in the `url` property of the response?

Comment: I just want to attach the params to the response so i don't have to slice the URL to get the pageGuid.

Comment: isn't the params with the GET request?

Comment: yeah I'm confused, you're already passing `pageGuid` as input to the method

Comment: Actually you guys are right. I am an idiot. The params are coming back on the URL. Is there a way i can make them a property instead of attaching them to the end of the url? something like body.append(pageGuid)